# How to send query request from AWS Lambda with Serverless Framework to AppSync GraphQL API?

Tags: aws-lambda, graphql, apollo-client, serverless, aws-appsync

I've been having this problem of understanding how to, in simplest way possible,send, by using AWS Lambda, query request over to a certain AppSync GraphQL API ( which has **API KEY auth mode**).

I'm sort of a beginner, hence I've been reading a lot, in search of useful tips and tutorials that might explain this, the closest I came to a solution is this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/building-a-client-app-node.html, which suggests using Apollo Client. 
My first question is, is this the best approach to my goal (using Apollo Client + AWS Lambda to send query,mutations to AppSync GraphQL API)? If not, what would be the best practice/way to do so?

Here's my current code based of the above mentioned tutorial:

```
const gql  = require('graphql-tag');
const AWSAppSyncClient = require('aws-appsync').default;
const AUTH_TYPE = require('aws-appsync-auth-link/lib/auth-link').AUTH_TYPE;
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
require('isomorphic-fetch');


module.exports.handler =  async function(event, context) {

    //console.log("before_client_setup");

    const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
      url: '******',
      region: '******',
      auth: {
        type: AUTH_TYPE.API_KEY,
        apiKey:'******'
      },
      disableOffline: true
    });

    //console.log("before_gql_query");

    const query = gql`
      query listJobs {
        listJobs{
          items {
            id title employer datePosted location url
          }
        }
      }
    `;

   //console.log("before_client_call");

    client.hydrated().then(function (client) {
      //Now run a query

      //console.log("before_client_query");

        client.query({ query: query, fetchPolicy: 'network-only' })   //Uncomment for AWS Lambda
          .then(function logData(data) {
              console.log('results of query: ', data);
          })
          .catch(console.error);
    });
}
```

**url, region, auth** parameters are hard-coded just to test if it works (I know that it's not a best practice), but when I invoke this function trough serverless framework with the command:`sls invoke -f streamFunction --stage stg` the result I get inside of console is: 
**null**

Expected result (which I got when using Postman and passing correct url and api key): 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAfRL.png

CloudWatch Logs aren't of any help either, as they are not giving useful insight into what the problem may be. Here's a screenshot of them upon being invoked:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKXsP.png

Any advices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I think the main problem was because I was using this syntax:

```
client.hydrated().then(function (client) {

      client.query({ query: query, fetchPolicy: 'network-only' })   //Uncomment for AWS Lambda
      .then(function logData(data) {
          console.log('results of query: ', data);
      })
      .catch(console.error);
});
```

inside of async function which is my lambda. Instead, **await** keyword should be used. Here's the whole code which solved the problem:

```
const gql = require('graphql-tag');
const AWSAppSyncClient = require('aws-appsync').default;
const AUTH_TYPE = require('aws-appsync-auth-link/lib/auth-link').AUTH_TYPE;
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
require('isomorphic-fetch');
module.exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
  try {
    const appSyncClient = new AWSAppSyncClient(
      {
        url: '******',
        region: '******',
        auth: {
          type: AUTH_TYPE.API_KEY,
          apiKey: '******'
        },
        disableOffline: true
      },
      {
        defaultOptions: {
          query: {
            fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
            errorPolicy: 'all',
          },
        },
      }
    );  
    const query = await gql`
      query listJobs {
        listJobs{
          items {
            id title employer datePosted location url
          }
        }
      }
    `;
    const client = await appSyncClient.hydrated();
    const data =   await client.query({query});
    console.log(data);

  } catch (error) {
    return context.fail(error);
  }
  return context.succeed("success");
}
```

And here are the logs from CloudWatch:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6AcB.png

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for giving AppSync a try! Glad you got the client setup figured out.